# Solving for $X$ in $\sum_{a,b} b a^T b^T X a = Y$

Tags: linear-solver, matrix-equations

Suppose I have $k$ pairs of $(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $Y$ is $d\times d$ and I need least squares solution for $X$ in the following

$$\sum_{(a,b)}^k  b a^T (b^T X a) = Y$$

This is equivalent to $d^2\times d^2$ linear system  $\sum_{a,b} (a\otimes b)(a\otimes b)^T$ , but I need an estimate in $O(k d^3)$ time, is that possible?

([notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-kronecker-solve.nb))

Comment: You cannot get $O(k)$ since the output has $d^2$ elements, so at the very least you need  $O(d^2)$ operations to write the output.

Comment: I have added parentheses, since that formula is not well-defined without them. Could you please confirm that this is the correct interpretation?

Comment: @lightxbulb ok good point, I need $O(d^3 k)$. In my application (neural net training) $d$ is $1000$ and existing operations take $O(d^2)$ storage and $O(d^3)$ compute, so I'm looking for similar complexity

Comment: @FedericoPoloni yes, good catch, I was missing parentheses there

Answer (score 2):

Conjugate gradient (in a matrix-less implementation) might be a good idea to try. You have a $d^2\times d^2$ symmetric positive semidefinite matrix for which you can compute the action of the matrix-vector product in time $O(kd^2)$. If the method converges reasonably fast you're set.

The method should converge naturally to the least-squares solution, at least if the system is compatible.